# prevent the input field being loaded on load

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I don't know how to put this question, so I will try my best to convey it. I have a JSP page in which I have a drop down box which gets populated from a bean class but the problem is I get an error while loading the page.

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.igate.cloud.migrator.util.GetVPCs" scope="page" />
                                     <select id="vpc" name="vpc" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose VPC"  disabled="disabled">
                                        <option value="" default selected>Select VPC</option>
                                            <c:forEach items="${obj.items}" var="items">    
                                                 <option>
                                                        ${items}
                                                 </option>
                                            </c:forEach> 
                                    </select>
```

I get an error saying "'${obj.items}' Property 'items' not readable on type com.igate.cloud.migrator.util.GetVPCs".
I think the problem is it is trying to fetch the values from bean class using obj.items. Any help or advice is most welcome. Thanku

Comment: The title is not related to your question details !!!
So, Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Getter method with method name as "*`getItems`*".  You are seeing exception as there is no getter for the `items`

For ex:

```
public class GetVPCs {
     private List items;

     public List getItems() {
        return this.items;
     }
}
```

Comment: I have done that ,but  I am passing parameters to the method which is selected by the user. So how can I stop this from getting loaded??